# How can I give what operation should be done on an element dynamically?

Tags: javascript, function, typescript

I am trying to create a library like JQuery using Typescript. I am trying to take a shortcut so that I don't have to repeat basically the same thing over and over again. The situation is this:

```
if (property=="color"){
            if(this.element_type=="class"){
                for(var i=0;i<this.element_focus.length;i++){
                    this.element_focus[i].style.color = value;
                }
            }
            if(this.element_type=="id"){
                this.element_focus.style.color = value;
            }
        }
```

I want a way to add .color in a dynamic way. For example, var what_style = .color so that I can write: this.element_focus.style.what_style=value; Is there any way to do something similar to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors):

```
this.element_focus.style[property] = value;
```